# Как показать html при полноэкранном режиме видео?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я могу при клике на кнопку сделать полноэкранный режим видео в видеоплеере

[image: видеоплеер]

Но когда видео в полноэкранном режиме, то весь html пропадает, как я могу его показать при полноэкранном режиме?

[image: полноэкранный режим видео]

Делаю полноэкранный режим

```js
fullscreen(val) {
  const video = this.getVideoElement;

  if (val) {
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
      video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      video.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
      video.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
},
```

HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <div class="videoplayer__inner">
      <video
        ref="video"
        class="videoplayer__video"
        autoplay
        src="https://cdn.coverr.co/videos/coverr-autumn-lisbon-5773/1080p.mp4"
      ></video>
      <div class="videoplayer__controls">
        <div class="videoplayer__progress">
          <div class="videoplayer__progress-time">01:04</div>
          <div class="videoplayer__progress-line">
            <div class="videoplayer__progress-slider"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="videoplayer__progress-time">10:00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="videoplayer__controls-block videoplayer__controls-volume">
          <button class="videoplayer__btn">
            <vVolumeIcon :classes="['videoplayer__icon', 'videoplayer__icon-volume']" />
          </button>
          <div class="videoplayer__volume-line">
            <div class="videoplayer__volume-slider"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="videoplayer__controls-block videoplayer__controls-state">
          <button class="videoplayer__btn">
            <vPrevIcon :classes="['videoplayer__icon', 'videoplayer__icon-prev']" />
          </button>
          <button class="videoplayer__btn">
            <vPauseIcon
              v-if="getPlay"
              :classes="['videoplayer__icon', 'videoplayer__icon-pause']"
            />
            <vPlayIcon
              v-else
              :classes="['videoplayer__icon', 'videoplayer__icon-play']"
            />
          </button>
          <button class="videoplayer__btn">
            <vNextIcon :classes="['videoplayer__icon', 'videoplayer__icon-next']" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="videoplayer__controls-block videoplayer__controls-screen">
          <button
            class="videoplayer__btn"
            @click="fullscreen = !fullscreen"
          >
            <vFullScreenIcon :classes="['videoplayer__icon', 'videoplayer__icon-fullscreen']" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Разворачивать на весь экран сайт (не видео) и изменить верстку так, чтобы видео было на 100vw и 100vh. Это же самое сделано и на самом ютубе...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, спасибо, помогло